# How do you handle the Back button in action bar?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried with this but nothing happens.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d("TEST", "Pressed the Back button.");
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is called as `up` button. Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17638892/1306419 answer on [Back button on Action bar - Android . How to go back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638558/back-button-on-action-bar-android-how-to-go-back/17638892#17638892). Basically override `onOptionsItemSelected()` See the [difference between up and back button](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) and how to [use up button](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back button oin action bar is Menu item with id `android.R.id.home`. Here is how you can handle click on up item:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            // do something useful
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnBackPressed Doesn´t refer to that button but to the button on the bottom of your screen (the one next to home)

what you are looking for is to customize behavoiour on the home button

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
       //TODO log here
        return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}`